# how post api with authentication identifier and secret in flutter

Tags: flutter, async-await, stateless

i want fetch data by post method with identifier and secret in flutter
where should i add "identifier" and "secret" in post method?
in postman they added to body and that works but i couldnt add these to flutter code:
[image: identifier and secret authentication in postman]

[image: flutter code]

Future post(String url, var data) async {

String url = 'https://member.example.com/includes/api.php';

var data = {

```
'identifier': 'identifier code otm7LE8OzlBmprXn',

'secret': 'secret code SXZgmDpX8miT31PSRQ',

'action': 'GetInvoices',

'userid': 6414,

'orderby': 'date',

'responstype': 'json',
```

};

try {

```
final response = await http.post(

  Uri.parse(url),
  headers: <String, String>{
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
  },
  body: jsonEncode(data),
);
```

} catch (e) {

```
print(e);
```

}
}

E/flutter ( 6118): result=error;message=Authentication Failed

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: E/flutter ( 6118): result=error;message=Authentication Failed

Comment: is this working correctly with Postman?

Comment: yes postman in form-data mode only works fine but in raw mode dont work (i added application/json to header for testing raw mode)
i add this to raw and didnt work:
{
      'identifier': 'identifier code mI4Q2otm7LE8OzlBmprXn',
      'secret': 'secret code SXZgmDpX8miT31PSRQ',
      'action': 'GetInvoices',
      'userid': '6414',
      'orderby': 'date',
      'responstype': 'json',
    }

Answer (score 0):

Remove jsonEncode from body: jsonEncode(data).

body: data works for me